# how to visualize a trimesh point cloud using Open3d in python

Tags: python, lidar, open3d

My code is as follows

```
import numpy as np
import trimesh
import open3d as o3d

point_cloud = trimesh.load('points.obj').vertices
cloud = trimesh.points.PointCloud(point_cloud)


o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([cloud],
                                  zoom=0.3412,
                                  front=[0.4257, -0.2125, -0.8795],
                                  lookat=[2.6172, 2.0475, 1.532],
                                  up=[-0.0694, -0.9768, 0.2024])
```

It says that i have the wrong type obviously, but can I convert it into the open3d type in some way?

I cannot load using open3d since the file is a .obj, and i wasnt able to load the .obj into open3d

Comment: Have you tried `open3d.io.read_triangle_mesh('points.obj')`?